# Suppressing Email Notifications when setSharing in GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

So, I have the following code snippet, it is part of a larger script that copies a folder of templates and customizes them for the individual user's location and data.  Problem with this script is:  Whenever I add an owner or editor for each of the folders and sheets, it sends an email notification for each, even though the person running the script had to authorize the script to run.  This results in about 11 notification emails being sent to the user's email. I don't like spam.

Is there a way to suppress the email notifications for each shared item and changed permission, and just send one summary email that the files and folders have been copied and configured?  I intend to include a link to the top level folder (destConfiguration) in the email.  My original summary intent is shown below the snippet in the commented out section.

Trust me, I have searched this one as thoroughly as I can imagine, but I start getting crossover into GMail Scripts and such.

```
  var destConfiguration = sourceConfiguration.makeCopy(targetFolder).setName(clinicId+ " Caseload Management Configuration").setOwner(userId).removeEditor(editor);

          /*snip*/

          //Display a confirmation message
          /*var mailTo = userId;
          var mailSubject = clinicID+" Caseload Mangement Tools";
          var mailCC = ccEmail;
          var mailBody = "Your settings and folders for your clinic's Caseload Management Tools have been configured and copied to your Google Drive.");
          MailApp.sendEmail(mailTo, mailSubject, mailBody, {name: "Mgmt Tools Bot"});*/
```

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2829  This says some people want it, but I don't see indications that anyone is tracking it.  Is there a workaround?

Also, it appears that it is only when setting owner that the notifications are sent, not when adding editors (but I would want to verify that isn't happening with my code).

Comment: Star the issue! the more we are, the more google is going to take interest in it.

Comment: I can't star it because I'm not the domain admin :(.  I tried to sign in with my private gmail account, but apparently it's looking for me to be an admin.  I'll try again after completely logging out of my work account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. Today all sharing modifications will send an email to the owner of the file.

Comment: Sadly, that appears to be the case.  I accidentally found the issues thread after I posted the question by doing a very broad search that I had zero expectation would return a result matching the very specific issue I was having.

Accepting your answer, sadly, as it is truth.